# Rearrange words in array to matching position calculating Levenshtein distance Php

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, fuzzywuzzy

Rearrange words in Array based on position of the first array. In my code there are two array my first array is the base array from which i am going to compare it with second array and make the position same as first array.

Consider 2 input by considering 1 input as base i am applying levenshtein(metaphone(each word database),metaphone(each word of bank)) then based on that arranging the words of bankdata in new array

`databaseName = LAL BAHADUR SHASTRI` 
`bankdata = SHASTRI LAL` source code will only rearrange bankdata and stored in in new array current output of `bankdata : LAL SHASTRI`

Rearrangement is happening properly just need to arrange words in array

```
        $db = 'LAL BAHADUR SHASTRI YADAV';
        $bank = 'SHASTRI LAL';
        $a = reArrangeArray($db,$bank);

        function reArrangeArray($db,$bank)
        {
            $dataBaseName = $db;
            $bankdataRows = [$db,$bank,];
            $dbWords = preg_split("#[\s]+#", $dataBaseName);     
            foreach ($bankdataRows as $bankdata)
            {
            $bankWords = preg_split("#[\s]+#", trim($bankdata));
            $result    = [];    
            if(!empty($bankWords))
                foreach ($dbWords as $dbWord)
                {
                $idx   = null;
                $least = PHP_INT_MAX;
                foreach ($bankWords as $k => $bankWord)
                    if (($lv = levenshtein(metaphone($bankWord),metaphone($dbWord))) < $least)
                    {
                    $least = $lv;
                    $idx   = $k;
                    }
                @$result[] = $bankWords[$idx];
                unset($bankWords[$idx]);
                }
            $result = array_merge($result, $bankWords);
            var_dump($result);
            }
        }
```

**Case 1: CURRENT OUTPUT**

```
        array (size=4)
        0 => string 'LAL' (length=3)
        1 => string 'BAHADUR' (length=7)
        2 => string 'SHASTRI' (length=7)
        3 => string 'YADAV' (length=5)

        array (size=4)
        0 => string 'LAL' (length=3)
        1 => string 'SHASTRI' (length=7)
        2 => null
        3 => null
```

**Expected Output**

I need array position as same as databaseArray

```
        $dbName = 'LAL BAHADUR SHASTRI YADAV';
        $bankName = 'SHASTRI LAL';

        array of db (size=4)
        0 => string 'LAL' (length=3)
        1 => string 'BAHADUR' (length=7)
        2 => string 'SHASTRI' (length=7)
        3 => string 'YADAV' (length=5)

        array of bankname (size=4)
        0 => string 'LAL' (length=3)
        1 => #
        2 => string 'SHASTRI' (length=7)
        3 => ###
```

if word not found in first array it should be place with # since position is 3 which dont have matching element it has 3 #

```
        array (size=4)
        0 => string 'LAL' (length=3)
        1 => string 'BAHADUR' (length=7)
        2 => string 'SHASTRI' (length=7)
        3 => string 'YADAV' (length=5)

        array (size=4)
        0 => string 'LAL' (length=3)
        1 => string 'SHASTRI' (length=7)
        2 => null
        3 => null
```

**Expected Output**

I need array position as same as databaseArray

```
        $dbName = 'LAL BAHADUR SHASTRI YADAV';
        $bankName = 'SHARI LAL';

        array of db (size=4)
        0 => string 'LAL' (length=3)
        1 => string 'BAHADUR' (length=7)
        2 => string 'SHASTRI' (length=7)
        3 => string 'YADAV' (length=5)

        array of bankname (size=4)
        0 => string 'LAL' (length=3)
        1 => #
        2 => string 'SHARI' (length=7)
        3 => ###
```

This case would be calculated based on `levenshtein(metaphone($bankWord),metaphone($dbWord))`

**Case 2**

Input :

```
$dbName = NikithaRani MohanRao $bankdata = Nikitha Rani Mohan Rao

Output : $newbankdata = NikithaRani MohanRao
```

It should concatenate the word if found concatenated in $dbName

**Note**

Position of word is calculated just need to shift word in array by comparing first array

[image: Expected Output]

[image: Problem Diagram]

Comment: I'm not sure I understood - you want to rearrange the second array as the values in the first one? and fill the empty spot with `#` as the index? (not my down vote but the question is not so clear...)

Comment: @dWinder yes i have added the expected output screenshot.yes you are right need to add # where word is not found

Comment: This start sound like matching problem. Maybe you should do it in brute force (`O(n*m^2)`) as calculate all option of levinstein distance and at each step take the minimum

Comment: @dWinder Hope that can solve the issue because each calculation is important. The use of doing this is i need to match the score of two strings that is why the array position should match.How can we implement brute force `(O(n*m^2))` to your below source code

Comment: Edit my answer again with the brute-force code (not sure if there is any better way for your constrains...)

Comment: @dWinder you made my day Legend Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the entire question but let try to solve only the rearrange the array issue:

```
$a1 = explode(" ", "LAL BAHADUR SHASTRI YADAV");
// sort $a1 to whatever order you need
$a2 = explode(" ", "SHASTRI LAL");

foreach($a1 as $key => $e) { // for each element set him or fill with "#"
    $res[$key] = in_array($e, $a2) ? $e : str_repeat("#", $key); 
}
```

[str-repeat](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-repeat.php) is duplicate the char for `x` times. This code ran in `O(n*m)` - it can be modify to `O(n)` if needed (when `n` is the number of element in the first array).

I hope that helps and if not feel free to comment

**Edited:**

First define function for finding the Levenshtein minimum distance:

```
function foundLevenshteinMinIndex($word, $arr) {
    $word = metaphone($word);
    foreach ($arr as $k =>$e)
        $a[] = levenshtein($word,metaphone($e));
    return array_search(min($a), $a);
}
```

Now used the same `$a1, $a2` as do:

```
foreach($a2 as $w) {
    $i = foundLevenshteinMinIndex($w, $a1);
    if (!isset($res[$i]) || (levenshtein(metaphone($a1[$i]), metaphone($res[$i])) > levenshtein(metaphone($a1[$i]), metaphone($w))))
        $res[$i] = $w;
}

for($i = 0; $i < count($a1); $i++) 
    if (!isset($res[$i])) // if not set in the index fill with "#'
        $res[$i] = str_repeat("#", $i);
// rearrange by int indexs
ksort($res);
```

**Edited 2**

Look at this implementation:

```
$a1 = explode(" ", 'LAL BAHADUR SHASTRI YADAV');
$a2 = explode(" ",'SHASTRI LAL NABA');

function getDist($a1, $a2) {
    foreach($a2 as $k1 => $w1)
        foreach($a1 as $k2 => $w2)
            $arr[$k1][$k2] = levenshtein(metaphone($w1), metaphone($w2));
    return $arr;
}

function getMin($arr) {
    $min = PHP_INT_MAX;
    $minX = $minY = null;
    foreach($arr as $x => $row)
        foreach($row as $y => $cell)
            if ($cell < $min) {
                $min = $cell;
                $minX = $x;
                $minY = $y;
            }
    return array($minX, $minY);
}

function removeIndex($arr, $x, $y) {
    unset($arr[$x]);
    foreach($arr as &$row)
        unset($row[$y]);
    return $arr;
}

$arr = getDist($a1, $a2);
while (count($arr) && count(reset($arr))) {
    list($x, $y) = getMin($arr);
    if (!isset($res[$y]))
        $res[$y] = $a2[$x];
    $arr = removeIndex($arr, $x, $y);
}

for($i = 0; $i < count($a1); $i++)
    if (!isset($res[$i])) // if not set in the index fill with "#'
        $res[$i] = str_repeat("#", $i);
ksort($res);
```

Notice this code has time complexity of `O(n*(m^2))` when `n` is the first array and `m` is the second one

Comment: thanks mate you have taken me close to the solution.But it should calculate the levenshtein(metaphone()) of both the words i.e $db = 'LAL BAHADUR SHASI YADAV';
$bank = 'SHASTRI LAL';
$newArrangedArray = 
[0]-LAL
[1]-#
[2]-SHASTRI
[3]-###

Comment: @daoootim so why not just sort `$a1` by `levenshtein(metaphone()` will that works?

Comment: yes that will work just have query how can i merge your snippet my code snippet i have used levenshtein(metaphone() **line 19**  can you please suggest about mergining of code

Comment: @daoootim Sorting `$a1` with `levenshtein(metaphone())` require 1 word for compare not 2. Can you please try to explain better how you define the order of `$a1`? Notice that your code set "SHASTRI" in index`1` as he is the only option in the bank array so he the closest to "BAHADUR" so your code basically does hat it should - the question is what you want him to do?

Comment: order of first string would be unchanged based on that my 2nd string bankdata will be changed there will be two arrays in which i will compare every word of 2nd string i.e bankdata with 1st string and then find then calculate `levenshtein(metaphone())` from which i will arrange the words of the string

Comment: word are different but the levenshtein(metaphone()) is less then that word would be considered at that index

Comment: @daoootim edited my answer - hope I understood you right now

Comment: my 0 index word i.e "LAL" is missing array (size=4)
  `0 => string '' (length=0)
  1 => string '#' (length=1)
  2 => string 'SHASTR' (length=6)
  3 => string '###' (length=3)` and when i pass 'SHASTRI LAL NABA' that NABA should be at 4 which is mismatch words  should be placed at the last index

Comment: On my computer is return the correct output - please recheck (probably extra space`" "`) see [here](https://codeshare.io/21yAYX). Why? `NABA` has min levistien with `LAL` so it should be at index `0`

Comment: i will let you know i am close to the solution just stuck with minute issue

Comment: @daoootim edited the first loop so will set new word only if new element has smaller levistien distance (also update the example in the snipt link

Comment: added problem image [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKEjv.jpg) NABA should be placed at the 3 position since while `levenshtein(metaphone(NABA),metaphone(YADAV)) = 3 and  levenshtein(metaphone(NABA),metaphone(BAHADUR)) = 4`  NABA will be at position 3 because 'YADAV' has least levenshtein as compare to 'BAHADUR'

Comment: All other components are placed correctly just need to arrange the remaining word NABA

Comment: when passing _$a1 = explode(" ", 'LAL BAHADUR SHASTRI YADAV');
$a2 = explode(" ",'SHASTRI LAL NABA RAO SINGH SANGRAM');_
as input getting `error Undefined index: Line 35` for this line $res[$y] = $a2[$x];  **when the string length of $a2 is greater** that time getting the error can you please suggest

Comment: @daoootim You're right. I updated the `while` loop condition. also added `if` statement before setting `$res[$y]` as I guess you want the best fit and not the one that follow (not sure if necessary but cannot harm :) )

Comment: This happens because `levenshtein` can return `-1` for too long string (see [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php)) - what should be done it depends on you - throw error?

Comment: Getting error for this line  `$res[$y] = $a2[$x];`  as Undefined index: **$db = MRS R NAGA MALLESWARAMMA'; $bank = 'NAGAMALLESWARAMMA RAJULAPATI';**  yes i will check and let you know dWinder

Comment: I didn't get error when running with your input. Result is: Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] => RAJULAPATI
    [2] => ##
    [3] => NAGAMALLESWARAMMA
)

Comment: [2nd version of your code](https://codeshare.io/2jxKKK)  I am using your second version of your code that was more beneficial for me on line 33 i am getting error

Comment: the 2nd version of code you provided which is more efficient to me because i dont want to crop the string can you please help out me with the change or you want me to raise new question for this

Comment: You can open new one if you want. I take [this](https://codeshare.io/5ZWZgQ) and run with PHP7 and worked fine